# How to convert List<object> into List<String[]> in my case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, webforms

I am trying to get the field values of selected rows from **devexpress AspxGridView**.

> I set to select only one row and not multiple row in AspxGridView. and then I want to get the field values on server side. for testing I am trying print on `button.text`

**Here is my code of Aspx**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="100%" SettingsBehavior-AllowSelectByRowClick="True" OnSelectionChanged="btnSearch_Click">
    <Settings HorizontalScrollBarMode="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupedColumns="True" ShowTitlePanel="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" />

    <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="True" />   --it will select only one row

    <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="True" />

    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Status" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="WorksheetID" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="POTitle" VisibleIndex="2" Width="200px" ExportWidth="100" MinWidth="100">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FromStoreName" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                            
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="FromDatePlaced" VisibleIndex="10">
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ToPlacementStatus" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="11">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>   
        ...
        ...           
    </Columns>

</dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

**Screen shot of selecting one row**

[image: select one row]

**Server side code**

```
public string[] Status { get; set; }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> listField = new List<string[]>();
        listField =(List<string[]>)ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues(Status); \\this line showing error

        \\btnSearch.Text = (string)Status.GetValue(0);
    }
```

> **Error msg:**
>
> Cannot convert type System.Collection.Generic.List to System.Collection.Generic.List

Comment: Your title says `List<string>` but your code shows that you declare a `List<string[]>`

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, I didn't notice that. Now I changed my title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast every object to a `string[]`:

```
List<string[]> listField = ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues(Status)
    .Select(obj => (string[]) obj)
    .ToList();
```

or with [`List(T).ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<string[]> listField = ASPxGridView1.GetSelectedFieldValues(Status).ConvertAll(obj => (string[]) obj);
```